# GitHub Actions can see Helm but not K3s installation when using seperate jobs

Tags: github, github-actions, kubernetes-helm, k3s

I am running into a bit of an annoying issue with GitHub Actions.

Currently, I have a action that runs through various Helm linting, validations etc.

I am using K3s which work fine with Helm when the action isn't seperated into jobs.

When I use seperate jobs in a single action file, for whatever reason, Helm cannot connect to K3s.

Below is my current action.yaml

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  setup-k3s:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Kubernetes
      run: |
        curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=777 sh -
        cat /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
        mkdir -p ~/.kube
        cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config

  setup-helm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup-k3s
    steps:
    - name: Set up Helm
      uses: azure/setup-helm@v1

  linting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup-helm
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2    
    - name: Validate Helm charts
      run: |
        helm lint

  dry-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: linting
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2      
    - name: Dry-run install Helm chart
      if: always()
      run: |
        helm install workflow . --values values.yaml --debug --dry-run

  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: dry-run
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2      
    - name: Install Helm chart
      if: always()
      run: |
        helm install workflow . --values values.yaml --debug

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2      
    - name: Run Helm tests
      if: always()
      run: |
        helm test run workflow
```

This is my older action.yaml which worked fine with K3 and Helm could see and connect to K3s.

```
name: Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Kubernetes
      run: |
        curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=777 sh -
        cat /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
        mkdir -p ~/.kube
        cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config

    - name: Set up Helm
      uses: azure/setup-helm@v1

    - name: Validate Helm charts
      run: |
        helm lint

    - name: Dry-run install Helm chart
      run: |
        helm install workflow . --values values.yaml --debug --dry-run

    - name: Install Helm chart
      run: |
        helm install workflow . --values values.yaml --debug

    - name: Run Helm tests
      run: |
        helm test run workflow
```

I have tried extensively googling the issue, and trawling through multiple configurations etc, but I cannot proceed and do not know why this isn't working.

Comment: Each job runs on a separate runner machine so that's expected as you're only installing k3s in the first job only in your first workflow. Whereas in the second workflow, all the steps are under the same job that's why it works fine. See [workflow basics](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows#workflow-basics) for more details.

Comment: @Azeem Ah, understand! Is there anyway of making it so it's still separated into Jobs for the sake of separation, as each job produces a metric-ton of logs? but each job shares the K3s?

Comment: You can host k3s publicly and use that. Or, you can use a self-hosted runner, install k3s on that, and all the jobs can share that. But, I don't see the point here as all those jobs have dependency on the previous job. Ultimately, this'll cost you most time. IMO, one consolidated job seems to be fine. About the generated logs, the steps are already separated (can be expanded or collapsed) so the separation is already there. Depending on your use case, you can redirect logs to files, update those as artifacts and process those later.